# the pause in latex

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I make a beamer in Latex. I write the following sentences:

```latex
 $S\in DSS_{n}\left( \mathbb{R}\right) $ if and only if there exists a \textbf{doubly stochastic matrix} $ D $ such that $ s_{ij}\leq d_{ij} $ for all $ 1\leq i,j \leq n $.
```

Now, I want to show just `$S\in DSS_{n}\left( \mathbb{R}\right) $` for the first time and secondly `$ s_{ij}\leq d_{ij} $`. After that show all sentences. How can I do this work in Latex?

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: Whenever you use \pause in beamer (or texpower) it creates a new slide.  Do you want multiple partial pages in a document?

Answer (score -3):

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  {\pause[1] $S\in DSS_{n}\left( \mathbb{R}\right) $} if and only if there exists a 
  \textbf{doubly stochastic matrix} $ D $ such that {\pause[2] $ s_{ij}\leq d_{ij}} $ for all $ 
  1\leq i,j \leq n $.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Why do you write `\left( \mathbb{R}\right)` when `(\mathbb{R})` is easier and has better spacing?

Comment: ...also, your scoping `{`...`}` incorrectly spans a math group `$`...`$`.